# keep PDO Commit or Rollback active across multiple scripts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, commit, rollback

the best way to explain my question is with an example

say i have 3 scripts;

first one is a form, on submitting this it goes to second script which processes the POST variables and Inserts them into the DB
on this page/script there's another submit button, that takes you to the third page where the Insert query is finally commited to the DB

is this possible?

or do commit/rollback have to be on the same script?

thanks

Comment: Not in several scripts (or actually, that would be a terribly difficult to set up and maintain, but not impossible if you call in a stateful application that keeps a connection). But simple is best: don't _do anything_ in the first & second scripts with the database. Store the data in a session, if you want to only commit in the 3rd: store the data in a session or the like, and run all your queries in that 3rd script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, commit/rollback has to be in the same *request* that started the transaction.

Another way of looking at this is that transactions must be resolved within the same database connection, and database connections (like any other resource) don't survive across multiple PHP requests.

As @Wrikken comments, you could save the uncommitted data in session data, or some other non-database holding space (e.g. memcached).

Another option is to save and commit the data in the database during each request, but add a column to your table for the state of the data. Therefore it would be physically committed with respect to database transactions, but it would be annotated as incomplete until you finish handling the third script.

I've implemented systems like this, for example for "shopping cart" style information. It also helps to run a daily cron job to delete old, unfinished data. Because inevitably, people do sometimes abandon their work in progress and never get to the finish step.

Comment: cool. thanks. thought that might be the case. yea, will put in DB, with extra column for the state of transaction. thanks